# Problems loading web page lazily with Scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I would like to scrape the articles of [this page](https://www.compraonline.grupoeroski.com/es/supermercado/2059698-Alimentos-Frescos/2059699-Frutas/). However, items of the page load via Ajax when I scroll it down. Up until now I have been trying to simulate the POST request that achieves this with no success. Here is the snippet of code that describes my problem.

```
import scrapy
class eroskiSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "eroski"
    allowed_domains = ['https://www.compraonline.com']
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.compraonline.grupoeroski.com/es/'
    ]
    counter = 0
    def parse(self, response):

        for sel in response.xpath('//nav[@class="navmenu"]/ul/li/div/ul/li'):

            cat_title = sel.xpath('a/@title')[0].extract()
            href = sel.xpath('a/@href')[0].extract()
            url = response.urljoin(href)

            print 'Parsing category ' + cat_title
            yield scrapy.Request(url, callback = self.parse_cat, dont_filter = True)
            break

    def parse_cat(self, response):

        category = response.xpath('//head/title/text()').extract_first()
        counter = 0
        for sel in response.xpath('//article'):

            counter = counter + 1
            print 'counter is ' + str(counter)

            description = sel.xpath('.//h2[contains(@class, "description_title")]/a/@title').extract_first()
            print description

        payload = {'pageNumber': '2', 't:zoneid': 'zoneScroll'}
        yield scrapy.FormRequest(url = response.url, formdata = payload, dont_filter=True)
```

If you run the code you can see how it loops forever for the same 20 items that appear when the page is first loaded. Therefore my intent of loading more articles with the FormRequest is incorrect. Any ideas on what is wrong?

Comment: what scrapy version are you using ?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry. Dumb question. I obviously forgot to use the callback.

```
yield scrapy.FormRequest(url = response.url, formdata = payload, dont_filter=True, callback = self.parse_cat)
```

Now we actually get the second page number after the first one. Aaaaa I am so stupid.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the solution, that´s the first important sign of intelligence ;)